# How are data splits of jobs allocated to nodes?

Tags: hadoop, cloud, distributed-computing

I was interested in modifying the way the input data splits of jobs were allocated to particular nodes.

I went through JobInprogress code of hadoop but couldn't get to know how actual allocation happens.

How are the input splits of a job distributed across nodes of cluster ?

Which Hadoop files do i need to go thru to understand allocation ?

Comment: Thanks praveen for response! But your response is about how task are assigned and the code related to it. I am a bit familiar with this. The assigntasks call in FIFO scheduler sees the jobs and tries to get a localmaptask or non-local one. The implementation of this call may be different. But i was interested in knowing HOW DATA SPLITS WERE ALLOCATED TO A PARTICULAR NODE WHEN THE SPLITS WERE CREATED FROM THE FILES ?.I want to CHANGE THIS ALLOCATION to see the difference in execution time of jobs when map tasks are executed on nodes where the data is local & non-local.

Answer (score 1):

Each input format like [MultiFileInputFormat](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.21/mapreduce/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MultiFileInputFormat.java) implements the [InputFormat#getSplits()](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.21/mapreduce/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.java) method where the InputSplits are calculated.

Comment: Modified the response based on the comment.